# Understanding the computation of Standard Error of Regression Coeficients (ISLR)

Tags: regression, statistics, variance

During my reading of Introduction To Statistical Learning, I reached this part and I'm facing a very hard time trying to understand what is being said:

[image]

The highlighted words are telling that this is how we can calculate the standard error of a simple linear regression coeficients.

The question is: the variance symbol used in the formulas is referring to the variance of what exactly? This is not explicit in the book.

Comment: Often "epsilon" is the error, but we would need more context to see. Does the textbook mention error somewhere above?

Comment: Y = β0 + β1X + epsilon.Equation 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Variance symbol (σ2) in the formulas is the variance of sampling error. And occasionally denoted as Var(ε). it is assumed that sampling error is unrelated to common variance.